# If I have two values, how do I push each of them to the same row in an array? - Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I am parsing a page with Nokogiri and am storing values like this:

```
contents[link[:href]] = content_page.css("p a")
copy = content_page.xpath('//p/text()[1]').text
```

Then I was pushing them on my `my_listing` array like this:

```
my_listing << contents[link[:href]]
my_listing << copy
```

But, what that does is creates a 2-element array for each entry.

So `contents[link[:href]]` is stored in `my_listing[0]`, while
`copy` is stored in `my_listing[1]`.

Whereas, what I would want to happen is, `my_listing[0][0] == contents[link[:href]]` && `my_listing[0][1] == copy`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you do a one-liner:

```
my_listing << [ contents[link[:href]], copy ]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `contents` is a hash?

If so, you can make an array like you want by simply using the `Hash#to_a` method.

```
{'a' => 123, 'b' => 456}.to_a
#=> [["a", 123], ["b", 456]]
```

---

```
contents = {}
contents['http://google.com'] = 'Its a google!'
contents['http://yeahoo.com'] = 'Like yahoo, but with some yeah!'

my_listing = contents.to_a

puts my_listing[0][0] #=> http://google.com
puts my_listing[0][1] #=> Its a google!
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the one-liner is more elegant :)